# Connecting two computers using an Ethernet cable

Tags: networking, ethernet, ping, telnet, crossover-cable

When you connect two computers using an Ethernet cable (Crossover) you are technically using layer 1 and 2 technologies.

Layer 1 = Ethernet cable (The signaling aspect)
Layer 2 = The computer's NIC adapters with their MAC addresses

My question is, where do the layer 3 technologies come from as you do need the IP address to ping, telnet, SSH, or other from one to the other computer.

Is layer 3 contained in the IP/TCP stack of the computers, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethernet is like a pizza. You've found the crust (layer 1) and sauce (layer 2). Your question is which slice are the toppings on?

Conceptually, the toppings are *everywhere* on a pizza. The practical implementation of this concept consists of a bunch of things spread across the pizza roughly evenly, with each slice having some of them. If some of your pizza slices completely lack pepperoni, they're not proper slices! All of these pepperoni, when you think about them together, implement the concept of *pepperoni layer*.

Similarly, OSI layers are conceptual and don't have to correspond neatly to any particular piece of hardware or software. The implementation of these concepts involve some concrete solutions. In the lowest layer (physical) these concrete implementations will be common between all network participants (slices), but as you go up the stack, layers will consist of multiple parts spread across networked devices. Pizza works the same way, the crust is common but next layers build on top of it. There's no single common pepperoni.

Each device has to have its own layer 2 and higher implementation. Their implementations follow the same standards, so they can communicate.

Comment: OK thanks for your descriptive answer! So in this case, 2 PC between the cable, there is no particular layer 3 phases, until it needs to use a router etc, despite needing an IP address for communication.

Comment: @Dougie No, there's always the 3rd layer. Without it there's no 4th, 5th etc - layers build on layers below them. 3rd layer is the one in which IP protocol exists. Both devices have to know that there's another IP-addressed device (possibly more than one) on the other end of the cable and what packets should be routed there. The fact that there are just 2 computers doesn't change how the network works at all.

Comment: OK perfect, that has made more sense! Thanks, will complete question!